# SupportMapFragment nested in Fragment makes map not reacting to gestures

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-3

I have problem with Google Maps V3. Basically I have application with HomeActivity (AppCompatActivity). In this activity I have HomeFragment (inherits from Fragment) and now what I want is to have SupportMapFragment from Google Maps library, so inside HomeFragment layout I put

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In HomeFragment onCreateView callback I have

```
mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
```

Map is showing, but the problem is I can't do anything - I mean I can't scroll or zoom this map, it is not responding.

I tried to put MapView instead of whole fragment and map was reacting to gestures. But this solution isn't perfect - for example isMyLocationEnabled doesn't show current location icon and click on button in right upper corner is not moving camera to location (yet callback is called).

Any idea how I can solve this one?

EDIT: Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="homeVM"
        type="viewmodel.home.map.HomeViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="detailVM"
        type="viewmodel.home.map.SheetDetailViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="shareVM"
        type="viewmodel.home.map.HomeSheetShareViewModel" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sidebarBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.openSidebar()}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_bg_rounded"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:tint="@color/warm_grey"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_warm_gray_24dp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapOptionsMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/white_bg_rounded"
        android:divider="@drawable/line_background_margin_8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapTypeBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.mapType()}"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_layers_warm_gray_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/warm_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.onArClick()}"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ar_warm_grey_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/warm_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myTrackerLocationBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.myTrackerLocation()}"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_on_warm_gray_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/warm_grey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myLocationBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.myLocation()}"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_on_warm_gray_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/warm_grey" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/trackerOptionsMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/white_bg_rounded"
        android:divider="@drawable/line_background_margin_8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapOptionsMenu">

        <view.AnimatedRefreshImageView
            android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.refresh(shareVM.items)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myLocationBtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTrackerLocationBtn"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/supertracking_btn"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.superTracking(shareVM.selected.id)}"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/drawable_superlive" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/trackersSheet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <activity.home.home.fragments.sheet.TrackersSheet
            android:id="@+id/list_sheet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            bind:items="@{shareVM.items}"
            bind:visible="@{shareVM.selected == null}"/>

        <activity.home.home.fragments.sheet.DetailSheet
            android:id="@+id/detail_sheet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            bind:isAutoSelect="@{shareVM.isAutoSelect}"
            bind:setAutoSelectTracker="@{shareVM.items[0]}"
            bind:tracker="@{shareVM.selected}"
            bind:viewModel="@{detailVM}"
            bind:visible="@{shareVM.selected != null || shareVM.isAutoSelect}">

        </activity.home.home.fragments.sheet.DetailSheet>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.github.stkent.amplify.prompt.DefaultLayoutPromptView
        android:id="@+id/prompt_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:prompt_view_background_color="@color/blood_orange"
        app:prompt_view_button_corner_radius="15dp"
        app:prompt_view_critical_feedback_question_negative_button_label="@string/prompt_view_feedback_negative"
        app:prompt_view_critical_feedback_question_positive_button_label="@string/prompt_view_feedback_positive"
        app:prompt_view_critical_feedback_question_title="@string/prompt_view_feedback_question_title"
        app:prompt_view_positive_feedback_question_negative_button_label="@string/prompt_view_rate_negative"
        app:prompt_view_positive_feedback_question_positive_button_label="@string/prompt_view_rate_positive"
        app:prompt_view_positive_feedback_question_title="@string/prompt_view_rate_title"
        app:prompt_view_thanks_display_time_ms="2000"
        app:prompt_view_user_opinion_question_negative_button_label="@string/general_no"
        app:prompt_view_user_opinion_question_positive_button_label="@string/general_yes"
        app:prompt_view_user_opinion_question_title="@string/prompt_view_question_title" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/productRating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@color/blood_orange"
        android:visibility="@{homeVM.productRatingVisibility}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productRatingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rating_popup_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productRatingMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rating_popup_message"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productRatingTitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/productRatingNoBtn"
            style="@style/Button.Rounded.Orange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rating_nothanks_btn"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.postponeRating()}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productRatingMsg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/productRatingYesBtn"
            style="@style/Button.Rounded.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/product_rating_answer_btn"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> homeVM.answerRating()}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productRatingMsg" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: please share your layout ? I have already gone through this problem but in my case I used the mapFragment inside NestScrollView

Comment: I've posted layout. @Shay Kin

Comment: @Shay Kin any idea?

Comment: I tried your code and the xml layout without the trackersSheet and it worked perfectly I do not know what your exact problem may be the map does not receive the events of touch.  did you test with the setOnclickListener on the map? to see if it recoi the touch event. or the fragment is completely hidden by the ConstraintLayout trackersSheet

Comment: @Shay Kin and that is weird, because if I put fragment with MapBox map, instead of Google map, it is working fine. How did you manage to receive gestures in NestScrollView? Maybe you did something I can use...

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem with my ScrollView but in my case I override the `dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)` method and in the body of this method I used this `Rect outRect = new Rect ();
                     mapFragment.requireView (). getGlobalVisibleRect (outRect);
                     if (outRect.contains ((int) ev.getRawX (), (int) ev.getRawY ())) {
                         rootScroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (true);
                         rootScroll.onInterceptTouchEvent (ev);
                     } `and it helped me to block key events on the ScrollView

Comment: but in your case I tested it yesterday with Maps **SDK for Android v.3.1.0 BETA** and it works fine you can see this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Finally. It wasn't Google Maps SDK issue, but something in code. We got this project in late state of development from other company and I wasn't aware of this.

It was all about this piece of code:

```
if (view is ViewGroup && !isHomeFragment()) {
        view.hideSoftKeyboardOnTouchOutside()
}

fun ViewGroup.hideSoftKeyboardOnTouchOutside() {
this.childrenRecursiveSequence()
        .filter { it !is EditText }
        .forEach {
            it.setOnTouchListener { view, _ ->
                view.hideSoftKeyboard()
                false
            }
        }
}
```

It was executed in base fragment onViewCreated callback on inheriting fragment view. Somehow it didn't affect MapBox map reaction to gestures unlike Google map, which was quite useless in that case.